# After using pip, I get the error "Scikit-learn has not been built correctly"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I'm using a Jetson Nano and I already tried reinstalling tensorflow (tried different versions) and numpy (also different versions). I'm using the `pip3` commands, since I'm using `python3` (version 3.6.9).
Downgrading everything didn't work, since Keras needs tensorflow >2.2
I also tried reinstalling scikit-learn, using the `--force-reinstall` flag.
Since it might be helpful, here is the full error message I receive when trying to run my program:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
ImportError: /home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/../../scikit_learn.libs/libgomp-d22c30c5.so.1.0.0: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LSTMMVMSTSF.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "/home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise_build_error(e)
  File "/home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 41, in raise_build_error
    %s""" % (e, local_dir, ''.join(dir_content).strip(), msg))
ImportError: /home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/../../scikit_learn.libs/libgomp-d22c30c5.so.1.0.0: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build:
__init__.py               _check_build.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so__pycache__
setup.py
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

Edit: I forgot to add information on the installation of scikit-learn. I used `sudo pip3 install scikit-learn`. The logs of that installment:

```
sudo pip3 install scikit-learn  Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting scikit-learn
  Downloading scikit_learn-0.24.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (24.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 24.0 MB 20.5 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in /home/nano/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.5.4)
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
Successfully installed scikit-learn-0.24.2
```

Comment: The error says scikit-learn is not built correctly, don't you think information on how you installed/built scikit-learn is kind of important? Also reinstalling keras and tensorflow does nothing since the problem is in scikit-learn (and sklearn does not depend on keras or tensorflow).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'm sorry I forgot the most important part. I have since edited the question with hopefully enough information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in another post:

There is no actual issue with installing, the order of imports just needs to be changed. In my case, I had to make `sklearn` the first import. Further reading [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14884)

Answer (score 4):

For those who cannot change import order (For example, library which uses sklearn raises error), I resolved this problem by setting environment variable `LD_PRELOAD` to path to `libgomp-d22c30c5.so.1.0.0`.

```sh
export LD_PRELOAD='/PATH/TO/libgomp-d22c30c5.so.1.0.0'
```

And execute program again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the tensorflow whl specific to aarch64 architecture. The prebuilt tensorflow binaries for aarch64 are provided by nvidia at the following location

https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/v44/

This link is for jetpack 4.4 (v44). Update the link based on the jetpack version you are using.

Comment: I tried it, result doesn't change. I used it both completly pre-built aswell as using specific versions of Tensorflow